# How to pass parameter to Couchbase query with @Query annotation?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, couchbase, sql++

I am trying to pass a parameter to custom query but it is not working.

My class is like this:

```
@Repository public interface CarRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<CarDocument, String> {
    @Query(
        value = "#{#n1ql.selectEntity} #{#n1ql.bucket} where cars.`:#{#carId}` is not missing; ")
    List<CarDocument> getCarDocumentsByCarId(@Param("carId")Integer carId);

}
```

The returned value is null. So it is not working.
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can pass parameters to a Couchbase query:

```html
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<User, String> {

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE username = $1")
    User findByUsername(String username);
}

User user = userRepository.findByUsername("johndoe");
```

The placeholder $1 is used to represent the first parameter passed to the method.

When you call the findByUsername method and pass a username as an argument, it will be substituted in the query at the placeholder's position.

Comment: I tried as you explained, #{#n1ql.selectEntity} #{#n1ql.bucket} where cars.`$1` is not missing; 
but it did not work.
I use @Query annotation from import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Query;

Comment: is carId is field or value. You can't parameter fields  in the document only value of field can be parametrized.  Update your post with sample document and what you are searching.

Answer (score 0):

use the spel expression `#{[<n>]}`

```
@Query("SELECT META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).id AS __id, META(#{#n1ql.bucket}).cas AS __cas, meta().id as id FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} #{[1]}")
@ScanConsistency(query = QueryScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS)
Flux<String> findIdByDynamicN1ql(String docType, String queryStatement);


List<String> all = reactiveAirportRepository.findIdByDynamicN1ql("ignored", "and 1=1").toStream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Gives the following.  Notice how it replaces the `#{[1]}` with the second argument.

2023-06-23 16:21:29,302 DEBUG core.ReactiveFindByQueryOperationSupport: 184 - findByQuery scope: null collection: null options: null statement: SELECT META(`9d4e29b1-6d3c-4c07-872d-241d232a3a0a`).id AS __id, META(`9d4e29b1-6d3c-4c07-872d-241d232a3a0a`).cas AS __cas, meta().id as id FROM `9d4e29b1-6d3c-4c07-872d-241d232a3a0a` WHERE `t` = "airport" and 1=1